# isnt there any descriptive step by step guide for MAAS + juju + Ceph + Openstach HA deployment?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ceph

I know this is the guide - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA , but Its not just descriptive enough? I saw in few question's answers that above link is still yet to be updated, but when?

I really want to use juju for openstack deployment, but its lacking in documentation, that's really annoying.

Comment: Unfortunately that page is the best we have right now, I'll ping someone on the openstack team to see about getting it updated.